# Pixelated hillshade from 5m elevation data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

I recently tried to create a hillshade of a valley in the Scottish Cairngorm mountains using some Digimap 5m elevation data (specifically the OS Terrain™ 5 DTM).

The data was downloaded in .asc format and I converted this to raster using the ArcToolbox Ascii -> Raster function. Then I mosaic'd the individual tiles together and used the hillshade tool to produce this: 
[image]

The view is approximately 10 miles across from left to right, should it be this fuzzy?

I'm very new to ArcMap and GIS in general.

Comment: I never realized the north slopes of hills in Scotland got so much sunlight.

Comment: A 5m resolution is fairly coarse, from my experience.  The hillshade looks correct to me.

Comment: Perfectly normal hillshade. If you see some artefacts at a closer zoom, repeat import from ascii. Make sure to pick Float type

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a 10m DTM.
Go to the Layer Properties -> Display -> Resample during display using: "Bilinear Interpolation"

[image: Hillshade with Nearest Neighbor resampling]

[image: Hillshade with Bilinear Interpolation]